# Stripe - Cancelling a subscription

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments

Update: The problem is that Stripe responds with the card_token when a new customer is created rather than the customer id. Probably I am doing something wrong.

I have setup Stripe on my Rails app and then integrate it with Devise. It works fine as it creates a new customer on my Stripe account and a new user on my Rails app. When a registration takes place I save the Stripe token in my users' table as stripe_card_token (from the stripe's respond).

I want users to be able to cancel their subscription.

I use the "stripe-ruby" gem and saw that there are methods inside the gem for subscription cancellation like the "cancel_subscription" method. However I am not sure how I call this method.

I checked Stripe's API for cancelling a subscription and the example is:

```
customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve({CUSTOMER_ID})
customer.subscriptions.retrieve({SUBSCRIPTION_ID}).delete()
```

but I don't have the customer's ID. The only attribute I save while making a customer is the token send on the Stripe's respond.

In the User.rb i create a customer with this method

```
  def create_a_customer
    token = self.stripe_card_token
    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
      :card => token,
      :plan => 1,
      :email => self.email
      )         
  end
```

When I create the customer I save the response.id as the token:

```
  handleStripeResponse: (status, response) ->
if status == 200
  $('#user_stripe_card_token').val(response.id)
  $('#new_user')[0].submit()
else
  $('#stripe_error').text(response.error.message)
  $('#stripe_error').show()
  $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false)
```

This response.id is the card's token and not customer's id...

I am confused on how to use the gem as it gives no examples, and the API asks about customer ID, instead the ID I get is the card's token. I am pretty sure I am missing something.

Any guidance, help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It looks like `Stripe::Customer.create` returns an id when it's successfully called. So you just need to grab that and save it.

Comment: I did. the ID that returns is something like "tok_3OtTuapKuf8FDc", which is token. What do I do with the token then? when I am asked to use customer ID to retrieve the customer I need an id like "cus_XXXXXXXXXX" which is for customer. Thanks for replying.

Comment: You shouldn't be getting a token returned when creating a customer, AFAIK. Tokens are returned when you create a charge. What happens if you change `response.id` to `customer.id`?

Comment: "response" is a parameter that comes from the handleStripeResponse object. Oh... thank you for saying that! Now i get why the ID's response is a token.

Comment: no. as I said, the response comes from the " handleStripeResponse: (status, response)"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46428/discussion-between-elendilthetall-and-stefanos-ioannou)

Comment: Linked to an updated version of this question, the solution is here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21457911/if-i-have-a-stripe-card-token-how-do-i-retrieve-customer-id

Answer (score 0):

When you call `Stripe::Customer.create`, it returns an `id` which is the stripe customer `id`. You can store that `id` in your database and use it to fetch the subscription for cancellation.

[Ref doc here](https://docs.stripe.com/api/customers/create)

snippet:

```
    customer = Stripe::Customer.create({
      name: 'Jenny Rosen',
      email: 'jennyrosen@example.com',
    })
    customer_id = customer.id
```

For the existing customer, you can make a search and retrieve the customer `id` as shown [here](https://docs.stripe.com/api/customers/search).

Comment: This response looks very good. It could be improved by adding some code snippets that demonstrate the functionality you're describing. For example, if the return value from creating a customer in stripe is a `customer` object, show how to reference the `id` property of this object. Similar for searching and retrieving by customer id, it would be helpful to show this in code.